# Ideal Resistance of Earth

Tags: electrical-resistance, earth

I am having trouble understanding why the ideal resistance of earth is 0? I can't find any plausible explanations. Can anyone explain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any simplified model of an electric circuit, the ideal resistance of a conductor is zero because that makes the calculations a lot easier.

This is justifiable because in many cases the actual resistance of a conductor is much smaller than other resistances, and tolerances, in the circuit and so it makes no practical difference.